# rails console cannot load such file but with one letter capitalized it works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, protocol-buffers, proto

ruby version: 2.7.3

Hi! I am very puzzled...

I have a file path `company/service/v1/my_proto_pb.rb`. When I tried to require it in rails console it gives the `cannot load such file` error:

```
2.7.3 :005 > require "company/service/v1/my_proto_pb"
Traceback (most recent call last):
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require': cannot load such file -- company/service/v1/my_proto_pb (LoadError)
```

HOWEVER when I capitalize the letter `v` to `V` it works:

```
2.7.3 :006 > require "company/service/V1/my_proto_pb"
 => true
```

But the `.rb` and `.rbi` file both exist in the `v1` folder. Why??? I cannot change the letter in code as it's auto-generated. Where exactly does the `require` look for and how can i check if what's being required exists or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... The issue was that my local code was not synced to the remote rails server correctly. Locally the files are in the `v1` folder but somehow remotely they are in the `V1` folder, which caused the issue.